# Using DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL to get code for a package but query is hanging

Tags: oracle

Why would this Oracle query that returns the code for a package hang indefinitely for all objects in the database?

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('PACKAGE', 'PKGNAME' , 'SCHEMANAME') AS DDL FROM DUAL
```

Is there a way to identify what is blocking the query result from being returned?

Comment: Are your packages wrapped? [Possible cause if they are](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2731415_1.html).

Comment: @Alex Poole - Ty for the reply. I don't think this is the issue because, once the DDL function hangs, it hangs for every procedure in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any performance problem, the key is to see wait-based historical data for the session in question. You can do this with OEM, certain 3rd party tools that do their own wait polling, or by a DBA running an ASH report (`?/rdbms/admin/ashrpt.sql`), a SQL monitor report (`dbms_sql_monitor` package) or by querying ASH data directly (which is what most all of the above actually use). Recent activity is in `v$active_session_history` (1 second per row) and older activity in `dba_hist_active_sess_history` (10 seconds per row). Or, you can query `v$session` repeatedly while the problem is occurring and get a rough idea of what's happening, though that's not very accurate.

In all of the above, once you identify the session in question you look for the predominant wait `event` being reported and on what `sql_id`. Your session could very well be stuck on a library cache lock or some other concurrency mechanism, or dictionary stats could be bad and internal queries of that package could be going sideways. If it's a lock or pin or mutex type situation, you'll need to find the blocker, or if one is not reported, look for a session in parse but not on a concurrency wait. A hang analysis might be of help as well. If you have a DBA, engage him/her for help as most of these tools are available only with elevated rights.